# tapestrydoc is an unknown tag

Tags: javadoc, tapestry

I'm working on a Tapestry component library and wanted to add javadoc using the maven javadoc plugin and Tapestry taglet.

**I added the following to my pom.xml:**

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <linksource>true</linksource>
                <taglet>org.apache.tapestry5.javadoc.TapestryDocTaglet</taglet>
                <tagletArtifact>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tapestry-javadoc</artifactId>
                    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
                </tagletArtifact>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

**And added following to my components java classes:**

```
/**
 * @tapestrydoc
 */
public class SomeComponent {
    ...
}
```

**Then I ran:**

```
mvn javadoc:javadoc
```

**But get the following:**

> ... warning - @tapestrydoc is an unknown tag.

And the component parameters are not added to the javadoc...

---

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this blog post for a howto: [JavaDoc Plugin For Component Reference Documentation](http://blog.tapestry5.de/index.php/2011/11/09/javadoc-plugin-for-component-reference-documentation/).
You need to add the tapestry config to the reporting plugin.

If this configuration is put into the reporting tag, it will only be used when generating reports via *mvn site*. Calling *mvn javadoc:javadoc* does not use the reporting tag. **However, you can easily solve your problem by putting it into the build tag.**

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
          <taglet>org.apache.tapestry5.javadoc.TapestryDocTaglet</taglet>
          <tagletArtifact>
             <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>                       
             <artifactId>tapestry-javadoc</artifactId>                       
             <version>5.3-rc-3</version>                   
          </tagletArtifact>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Oops, I just repeated your error instead of fixing it. See the updated answer (use the <build> tag!)

Comment: So if you want it to work with both **mvn site** and **mvn javadoc:javadoc**, is the preferred solution to have the plugin listed in both sections?  (build and reporting)